# Heap corruption detection for iOS device programming

Tags: ios, xcode, heap-corruption

Is there any function which detects heap corruption like [_heapchk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/2xse74he.aspx) for iOS device, not simulator?

[Guard Malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) is nearst, but it works in iOS Simulator, not iOS device. My app causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS by accessing null pointer only in device.

---